# Why are the outputs of this pseudo random number generator (LFSR) so predictable?

Tags: hardware, verilog, fpga, hdl

Recently I asked here, how to generate random numbers in hardware and was told to use an LFSR. It will be random but will start repeating after a certain value.

The problem is that the random numbers generated are so predictable that the next value can be easily guessed. For example check the simulation below:

[image]

The next "random" number can be guessed by adding the previous number with a +1 of itself. Can someone please verify if this is normal and to be expected.

Here is the code I used for the LFSR:

```
    module LFSR(
    input clock,
    input reset,
     output [12:0] rnd 
    );

wire feedback = rnd[12] ^ rnd[3] ^ rnd[2] ^ rnd[0]; 

reg [12:0] random;

always @ (posedge clock or posedge reset)
begin
    if (reset)
        random <= 13'hF; //An LFSR cannot have an all 0 state, thus reset to FF
    else
        random <= {random[11:0], feedback}; //shift left the xor'd every posedge clock
end

assign rnd = random;

endmodule
```

The location of the bits to XOR are picked up from here: [The table page 5](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp052.pdf)

Comment: Wait until the '1's reach the MSB, and then see if the subsequent numbers are still "predictable"...

Comment: My apologies.  I responded in haste and anger.  This was obviously inappropriate on my part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LFSR only generates **one** random bit per clock. It doesn't generate a new (in your case) 13-bit number each cycle. The other 12 bits in `rnd` are just the old random values, so it will not appear very random.

If you need a 13-bit random number, then you must either sample LFSR every 13 cycles, or put 13 LFSR in parallel with different seeds, and use the 13 zero bits as your random number.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to get it to work by sampling the resister every 13 cycles, as you suggested. And it is now random, so by this method now is it true random? that is no longer pseudo? I avoided your parallel implementation as it would be impractical to repeat all that code for say a 100 bit LFSR.

Comment: No, it's still pseudorandom, as the next number could be predicted by knowing the algorithm used to produce it and the current state of the system. But a good pseudorandom is probably just as good as true random for most purposes (non-security related).

Comment: You don't have to wait 13 clock cycles to get 13 bits. You can unroll the loop and add more XOR to predict what the value will be in 13 cycles. Of course, this is a whole lot of logic so it may not work for you.

Answer (score -1):

An LFSR is most certainly not 'random' in any real sense whatsoever.  To quote Von Neumann "Any one who considers arithmetical methods of producing random digits is, of course, in a state of sin."  I haven't looked up whether the feedback terms you've chosen are maximal, meaning that they'll provide a sequence with a length equal to the number of bits in your LFSR, but that's the best you can do.

So yes, the next value in your LFSR is extremely predictable.  If you need something more securely 'random' you need to look into cryptographic methods, these depend on a secret key of course, and are also much more computationally intensive than an LFSR.  You 'get what you pay for' though.

Incidentally, a system where you get predictable 'random' numbers is highly useful in it's own right.  Usually for simulation purposes.